# Detect if script file is used as script or open in browser tab to view the content

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect if the user opens the script file in the browser tab to view it or if the scripts load as `<script>` tag or a different way of loading scripts like ES Module import?

I've had this idea to add syntax highlighting and generate HTML output for script files (using Service Worker) when the user opens the script in a new tab, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: If user opens script as URL, it will not be executed by browser, just source code will be seen - so that's how you can "detect" it

Comment: @Justinas no, because on the service worker level both are just text. It's the same as detect on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've found the difference:

When the script is loaded as a script the request got this header:

```
Accept: */*
```

and when open in a new tab it get this instead:

```
Accept:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
```

So you can detect if `Accept` header matches `"text/html"`